# How to create Maven Jar file when tests contain JUnit @Test annotations and no main class

Tags: maven, junit, maven-3, maven-jar-plugin

I have 3 tests stored under a package that all take advantage of the JUnit @Test annotation. I do not have a main class in the project. Naturally, I can go Run As > Maven Test and all 3 tests will get executed.

I created a Jar executable file using the the Install command, but when I try to run the Jar file I get the message - "No main manifest attribute" message.

What is the solution for dealing with this in Maven?

I know that in Gradle, you do not need a main class to run the Jar executable.

Alternatively, would I need to create a main class containing a main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
List tests = new ArrayList();
tests.add(TestOne.class);
tests.add(TestTwo.class);

for (Class test : tests){
    runTests(test);
}
}

private static void runTests(Class test){
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(test);
for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()){
    System.out.println(failure.toString());
}
}
```

That kind of feels counter-intuitive to me however.

Comment: I don't understand how you want to run a JAR with no main class?

Comment: I have 3 separate tests that all contain @Test annotations, but perhaps I do need a main class, if so how do I go about creating that?

Comment: But how do you intend to run it, at least conceptually? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well I would like it to execute the tests, just as it does when I run the Test command

Comment: Do you want to package your tests in a jar file? Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828416/generate-test-jar-along-with-jar-file-in-test-package

Comment: What you're trying to achieve, and why, is really unclear. I can only guess you want to run tests from another JAR during the build of your project, so maybe look into [`dependenciesToScan`](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#dependenciesToScan) of the Surefire plugin...

Comment: That looks useful, however when I run that it is still giving me the message "No main manifest attribute" so still scratching my head

Comment: Hi Tunaki, I am not sure what is unclear about it? So I created a Maven project that contains 3 JUnit tests in my automation framework that all use the @Test annotation. So I can run those tests using Run As > Maven Test. Now I would like to produce a build of the project and deploy as a Jar file, that when executed will of course execute those tests from the 3 JUnit tests. Does that make it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Generate test-jar

You could add this into your pom.xml to generate a jar with your all your tests:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

## Execute test class

Then, execute the tests this way:

```
java -cp yourproject-1.0.0-tests.jar:junit-4.12.jar:otherdependencies.jar \ 
     junit.textui.TestRunner com.xyz.SomeTest
```

You need to add all your required dependencies in the `-cp` arguments.

## Test Suite

Each test must be executed one by one, but you could [create a testSuite](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-5-suite-test/), so you can easily execute all tests with a single command:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        SomeTest.class,
        SomeOtherTest.class
})
public class SuiteAbcTest {
    //normally, this is an empty class
}
```

and execute the Test Suite:

```
java -cp yourproject-1.0.0-tests.jar:junit-4.12.jar:otherdependencies.jar \ 
     junit.textui.TestRunner com.xyz.SuiteAbcTest
```

Comment: Excellent Alex, will give this a go and get back to you!

Comment: by the way, this assumes that your tests are in the maven's test folder: `src/test/java` (not in `src/main/java`)

Comment: Ahh yes, I tried to compile using this but am getting some compilation error that says my package named test does not exist. Will try and resolve it. Will I still need a TestRunner class?

Comment: Alex, I think actually this assumes my tests are in src/main/java and not src/test/java? My tests are stored in src/test/java under a package called test, how do I reference those in the SuiteAbcTest class?

Comment: SuiteAbcTest must also be in `src/test/java`. Everything test related in the test folder. Then `maven-jar-plugin` will generate a jar with the tests classes, which you'll then be able to run with the TestRunner.